# Populate multiple dropdown lists with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdown lists to populate from sql database using PHP and javascript/ajax.
First list starts with filled options, second list populates from database depending on selection. All this works fine and I echo the entire second list from PHP.
Problem is: I cant get the second drop down box to repeat another "onchange" function. Tried many combinations with no luck. Where does the second javasript function belong ? In the html or php ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

html with first javascript function

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Test</title>

<script>
function getdate(str){
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("dateinput").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("dateinput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form id="book" name="book" action="unfinished.php" method="post">
  <p align="center"> 
    <select name="cityinput" id="cityinput" onchange="getdate(this.value)">
      <option value="0" selected>City</option>
      <option value="1">Brisbane</option>
      <option value="2">Sydney</option>
      <option value="3">Melbourne</option>
      <option value="4">Adelaide</option>
      <option value="5">Perth</option>
    </select>
  </p> 
    <div id="dateinput"></div>
  <p align="center"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form></p>
</body>
</html>
```

php file

```
<?php
require'connect.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');

$q=$_GET["q"];
$sql="SELECT date AS date FROM schedule WHERE lounge = '".$q."' AND date >= NOW() AND date <= NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY
ORDER BY date asc"; 

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
$i=0;
echo"<center><select name='dateinput' id='dateinput'></center>";

while ($i < $num) {
    $datum=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
    $day = date('l jS M', strtotime($datum));
    echo "<option value=$datum>$day</option>";
    $i++;
}

if (!mysql_query($query)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Put the function into the html file and write the call of it into php (<select name='dateinput' id='dateinput' onchange='...'>), then everything should work.

Comment: ❗Before you write any more SQL interfacing code, please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You're using `$_GET` data in your query without even a hint of proper escaping. You **cannot** do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second Javascript function will also belongs to html file. and Attach the event (on which you want to call the second function) from your PHP file.

```
<select name="dateinput" id="dateinput" onchange="......."></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Kaljak and Guri, finally got it working as suggested and with a separate PHP file for each javascript function in the html.